# Entity-Framework Core Multi-Level dynamic query

Tags: sql, database, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to do a multi-level category with self join, but when i tried to get the data dynamically i couldnt so i wrote this query which is not dynamic any ideas how to make it dynamic
`

```
var data = Context.MultiLevelCategories
                .Where(mlc => mlc.ParentCategoryId == null)
                .Select(mlc=>new MultiLevelCategoryDetailsDto()
                {
                    Id = mlc.Id,
                    Name = mlc.Name,
                    ParentId = mlc.ParentCategoryId,
                    Children = mlc.Children.Select(mlc1 => new 
                                       MultiLevelCategoryDetailsDto()
                    {
                        Id = mlc1.Id,
                        Name = mlc1.Name,
                        ParentId = mlc1.ParentCategoryId,
                        Children = mlc1.Children.Select(mlc2 => new     
                                       MultiLevelCategoryDetailsDto()
                        {
                            Id = mlc2.Id,
                            Name = mlc2.Name,
                            ParentId = mlc2.ParentCategoryId,
                            Children = mlc2.Children.Select(mlc3 => new 
                                       MultiLevelCategoryDetailsDto()
                            {
                                Id = mlc3.Id,
                                Name = mlc3.Name,
                                ParentId = mlc3.ParentCategoryId,
                                Children = mlc3.Children.Select(mlc4 => new 
                                        MultiLevelCategoryDetailsDto()
                                {
                                    Id = mlc4.Id,
                                    Name = mlc4.Name,
                                    ParentId = mlc4.ParentCategoryId
                                })`enter code here`
                            })
                        })
                    })
                })
```

`

Comment: What's the dynamic meaning in your question?

Comment: i don't know how many levels there will be , so i need to get all the data with all the levels

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the navigation property can help you, but be careful with the cycle reference.

Read efcore documents:

- [Related data and serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/serialization)
- [Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key)

Comment: Please describe how instead of referring to outside sources that may disappear any time. Also, *which* navigation property? They already use navigation properties.

Comment: Learning to read documents, not complains